# google-api-java-client JSON parser on Android produces an empty self.request.body on GAE

Tags: python, android, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client

This is related to another [question about URL shortener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724270/). The code for URL shortener works fine, on both standalone Java and on Android. However, when re-using this code to communicate to a custom Google App Engine application, the code works perfectly fine on standalone Java, but produces an empty self.request.body when used from Android. **Why?**

To reproduce this behaviour, run the code below, on android, once with Google shortener URL:
`https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url`, and once with a custom URL to a web server. 
The same code on standalone java produces exactly the same request (as expected) in both cases. On Android, in the case of custom URL, the content body is empty and content-length is not set. 
I'm running google-api-java-client 1.2.2-alpha, with jackson 1.7.1.

The code snippet:

```
    HttpTransport transport = GoogleTransport.create();
    HttpRequest request = transport.buildPostRequest();

    // Change this URL below from Google Shortener URL, to a custom URL,
    // and the code on Android produces an empty body and Content-Length is not set
    request.setUrl("GoogleAppEngine url goes here");

    JsonCContent content = new JsonCContent();
    GenericData data = new GenericData();
    data.put("id", "whatever");
    content.data = data;
    request.content = content;
    HttpResponse response = request.execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done some debugging, and this is what turns out:

- by default, implementation on Android picks Apache HTTP client to do the low level transport. The code there is bare minimum, and it looks as if it does not set properly the Content-Type and Content-Length of the request. The request goes out, but, some (most) picky web servers skip the body. Google web servers seem to be handling that ok. So, it seems to work fine for Google servers, but not for other web servers (this is a bit weird, but, this is beyond the point of my problem).
- by default, on Java, java.net.HttpURLConnection is picked for low level http transport. This implementation is more verbose, and sets all the required fields neatly. Content-Length is there, so is the Content-Type and all the other fields. The JSON content gets serialised, and all the webservers are happy. Including my custom GAE app.

So, on Android, the following workaround solves the problem:

Put the following call:

> HttpTransport.setLowLevelHttpTransport(new com.google.api.client.javanet.NetHttpTransport());

BEFORE you do the `request.execute()`

This way, on Android, you'll use the transport that actually works (more tidy request is formed).

ps. As it is often in life, I got lazy, asked the question, hoping for someone to solve it for me. Ended up debugging and solving it myself PLUS had to write all that. Extra work - but I guess, for everybody else benefits. Hope others will find it useful.

ps.2. google api java client rocks now ;)  Thanks to the authors for putting up good work.

Comment: Thank you for investigating it and writing out your analysis and thoughtful feedback.  I'm still interested in eventually trying to figure out what is faulty in the Apache HTTP client HTTP transport implementation.  By the way, in version 1.3 under development, the HTTP transport implementation used won't be hidden any more, which I think would have made your debugging effort easier.